# Throwing a die three times

Tags: probability, combinatorics, dice

If I throw one die three times then each time the probability of getting a $6$ is $p={1 \over 6}$.

**EDIT**

If I want to know the probability of getting at least one $6$, then my intuition (which is clearly wrong) is that I observe three experiments and each time I have a chance of ${1 \over 6}$. So I sum up all ${1 \over 6}$ which yields $3 \cdot {1 \over 6}$.

However, it should be $p= 1-\left({5\over 6}\right)^3$.

Why is $3 \cdot {1 \over 6}$ wrong?

Comment: Please explain *why* you would make that guess.  Offhand, I don't see it at all.  I could see it as the guess for at least one $6$ ("I get $6$ on the first roll or the second or the third") but not for at least two.

Comment: you seem to add the probability for every throw? but in the first throw you have 1/6, the second 1/6 so 1/36 to have  2 consecutive 6.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, “and” translates to multiplying probabilities together, “or” leads to adding them (with correction for non-independence).

Comment: @saulspatz, after reconsidering the problem I have in my mind, I edited/changed my question a bit. I hope it doesn't cause too much confusion. Any comments are welcome :)

Comment: This question is clearer than your original question.  However, changing the question after it has been answered invalidates those answers.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig, sorry for the inconveniences. I will keep that in mind for future questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only ask why your intuition is wrong, that is the question I will answer.

When you add When you add $\frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{6}  + \frac{1}{6} $ you are double counting some of the possibilities.  For example, the result $(6,6,6)$ was counted three times.  And any outcome that has more than one $6$ was counted more than one time.

Comment: As we are currently discussing in lecture the rule of adding probabilities I wonder if I can alternatively describe my mistake as follows: Let be $A:=\{6, x, y\}$, $B:=\{x, 6, y\}$ and $C:=\{y, x, 6\}$ sets of the sample space $\Omega:= \{(x, y, z)\vert x, y, z \in \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}\}$ and $P(A)$, $P(B)$ and $P(C)$ be the respective probabilities that I get a $6$ on the first, second or third throw. I am only allowed to add them if the sets $A, B$ and $C$ are disjoint. As the three sets are clearly not disjoint it contradicts the rule of adding probabilities.

Answer (score 0):

The probability of obtaining a 6 is the same for each throw.  Therefore, this is a [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) problem.  The probability of exactly $k$ successes in $n$ trials, each of which has probability $p$ of success is
$$\Pr(X = k) = \binom{n}{k}p^k(1 - p)^{n - k}$$
where $p^k$ is the probability of $k$ successes, $(1 - p)^{n - k}$ is the probability of $n - k$ failures, and $\binom{n}{k}$ is the number of ways exactly $k$ successes can occur in $n$ trials.

When tossing a fair die, the probability of obtaining a six is $1/6$ for each trial.  Hence, the probability of at least one success is 
\begin{align*}
\Pr(X \geq 1) & = \sum_{k = 1}^{3} \binom{3}{k}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^k\binom{5}{6}^{3 - k}\\
              & = \binom{3}{1}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^1\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^2 + \binom{3}{2}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^2\binom{5}{6} + \binom{3}{3}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^3\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^0\\
              & = \frac{1 \cdot 3 \cdot 1 \cdot 25}{6^3} + \frac{3 \cdot 1 \cdot 5}{6^3} + \frac{1 \cdot 1 \cdot 1}{6^3}\\
              & = \frac{75 + 15 + 1}{6^3}\\
              & = \frac{91}{216}
\end{align*}

*M D's answer explains why your intuition was incorrect.  What follows supplements M D's answer.*

Your intuition led you to count each outcome as many times as a six appears, which is why you obtained 
\begin{align*}
\Pr(X \geq 1) & = \sum_{k = 1}^{3} \color{red}{k}\binom{3}{k}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^k\binom{5}{6}^{3 - k}\\
              & = 1\binom{3}{1}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^1\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^2 + \color{red}{2}\binom{3}{2}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^2\binom{5}{6} + \color{red}{3}\binom{3}{3}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^3\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^0\\
              & = \frac{3 \cdot 1 \cdot 25}{6^3} + \frac{\color{red}{2} \cdot 3 \cdot 1 \cdot 5}{6^3} + \frac{\color{red}{3} \cdot 1 \cdot 1 \cdot 1}{6^3}\\
              & = \frac{75 + \color{red}{2} \cdot 15 + \color{red}{3} \cdot 1}{6^3}\\
              & = \frac{75 +\color{red}{30} + \color{red}{3}}{216}\\
              & = \frac{\color{red}{108}}{216}\\
              & = \color{red}{\frac{1}{2}}
\end{align*}

Comment: I calculated the probability for at least two times the same number instead of at least two time a $6$. I edited my question.